# Regular expression matching {{html ... }} outside of {{code}}{{/code}} blocks

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression in **Java** to find all instances of {{html ...}} outside of {{code}} blocks. I've tried a variety of expressions, but they all seem to either be too greedy or too stingy.

The sample string I have been working on is:

```
{{code}}
  This is some plain text.
  {{html clean="false"}}
    This text is inside the html macro
  {{/html}}
{{/code}}
{{code}}
{{/code}}
blah
{{html clean="false2"}}
{{/html}}
{{html clean="false3"}}
{{code}}
```

I am expecting the regex to match the following strings:

```
1. {{html clean="false2"}}
2. {{html clean="false3"}}
```

I've been able to match all instances of {{html...}} via the regex:

```
\{\{html.*?\}\}
```

which returns

```
1. {{html clean="false"}}    <-- don't want to match this as its within {{code}} blocks
2. {{html clean="false2"}}
3. {{html clean="false3"}}
```

But haven't had any luck restricting via {{code}} blocks (using both positive & negative lookaheads/lookbehinds).

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If the `{{code}}` blocks can be nested, then regex won't work for this all on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A really common way of solving this problem is to use capture groups to distinguish when a match is in the correct context.

Consider this regex:

```regex
\{\{code}}.*?\{\{/code}}|(\{\{html.*?}})
```

It will cause the regex to match `{{code}}` blocks, but it will therefore keep anything within that block from being matched in the right hand side of the alternation `|` (in the capture group).

For more information, read [The Best Regex Trick Ever](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html) (from rexegg.com).

```
String regex = "\\{\\{code}}.*?\\{\\{/code}}|(\\{\\{html.*?}})";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.DOTALL).matcher(str);
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
while (m.find()) {
    String match = m.group(1);
    if (match != null) {
        matches.add(match);
    }
}
```

[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/N7JbPa)

Comment: @4castle I know this is a old post but would like to know (based in your answer) if it is possible, using `preg_replace` to change something, **but only if outside a specific tag**, like outside a `form` or a `table` tag. Thank you!

Comment: @n.h. I don't know enough PHP to know exactly how to formulate it, but yes, this kind of regex strategy can do that (though an HTML/XML parser may be a better solution).

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution assuming there isn't an absurd amount of lines would be for example set up a `boolean isInCode = false` variable, then parse through each line using a for loop and set `isInCode = true` whenever `{{code}}` is found and `isInCode = false` whenever `{{/code}}` is found. Then whenever `{{html}}` is found and `isInCode == false` then you know your conditions are met

Comment: Maybe an `int` instead of a `boolean` in case `{{code}}` can be nested.

Comment: Ya I went under the assumption that there wasn't any case in which `{{code}}` could be nested, but if so then use an int and increment/decrement accordingly.

Comment: OP mentions that a "string" need to be searched for `html`. It is not a file. Then you need to split form an array and run this logic. and OP specifically asks for regex.

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative look ahead to assert that `{{code}}` appears *before* `[[/code}}` (or neither appear) after the match:

```
(?s)\{\{html[^}]*\}\}(?=(.(?!\{\{/code\}\}))*(\{\{code\}\}|$))
```

---

Some test code:

```
String input =
        "{{code}}" +
        "This is some plain text." +
        "  {{html clean=\"false\"}}" +
        "    This text is inside the html macro" +
        "  {{/html}}" +
        "{{/code}}" +
        "{{code}}" +
        "{{/code}}" +
        "blah" +
        "{{html clean=\"false2\"}}" +
        "{{/html}}" +
        "{{html clean=\"false3\"}}" +
        "{{code}}";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?s)\\{\\{html[^}]*\\}\\}(?=(.(?!\\{\\{/code\\}\\}))*(\\{\\{code\\}\\}|$))");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Output:

```
{{html clean="false2"}}
{{html clean="false3"}}
```